# Prevent function stopping at first condition met

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

May be this is kind of a beginner question... I'm trying to prevent a function stopping when it met first condition. Here is my example:

```
// Array of values
const valArray = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// Array of index values
const indArr = [0, 2];

const multipliedVal = valArray.map((val, index) => {

    for (let i of indArr) {
        // Case 1
        if (index == i) return val * 3; 
        // Case 2
        if (index == i) return val * 3; 
        else return val;
    }

});

console.log(multipliedVal);
```

In case 1 it outputs:

> Array [3, undefined, 27, undefined]

In case 2 it outputs:

> Array [3, 4, 9, 16]

I want to apply case 2 in a way it will multiply values of valArray by 3 if their index are 0 and 2 (like defined in indArr), but map function stops running after first condition met. It does multiply 1 by 3, but not 9. I want the output to be:

> Array [3, 4, 27, 16]

I tried some other stuff with the splice method but did not figure that out. I bet some recursion would be involved with what I'm trying to achieve, but can't figure out how to do that.

May be someone can help? Thanks.

Comment: Don't return from the `for .. of` loop, `break` it.

Comment: What do you refer to by "case 1" and "case 2"? There's only one output in your code.

Comment: @Bergi it was just to illustrate the problem. Yes just one output. Just ignore Case 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `index` is present in `indArr` using `indexOf`. If so then multiply the value and return else return the value

```js
const valArray = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// Array of index values
const indArr = [0, 2];

const multipliedVal = valArray.map((val, index) => {
  if (indArr.indexOf(index) !== -1) {
    return val * 3
  }
  return val;

});

console.log(multipliedVal);
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution.